# Bash script to find factorial

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

The program takes input but show the following errors, how to resolve those errors ?
[image]

Comment: Line 7 is missing the closing backtick.

Comment: okay but still not working

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, copy and paste the actual text. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: when dealing with syntax issues consider cutting-n-pasting your code (plus appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a space after `[` and before `]`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the number to find it's factorial"
read number
total=1
counter=1
while [ $counter -le $number ];
do
    total=` expr $counter \* $total`
    counter=` expr $counter + 1`
done
echo $total
```

Working here on Ubuntu:

```
$ ./factorial.sh 
Enter the number to find it's factorial
5
120
```

Answer (score 2):

`[` is not mere syntax, it's a ***command***, therefore it needs space to separate it from its arguments.

```sh
while [ $counter -le $number ]
# .....^....................^
```

Make sure you validate that `number` is actually only digits.

Some other comments:

- Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` -- see
  https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006
  for more details.
- bash can do arithmetic, you don't need to call out to `expr`. See
  [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)
  and [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)
  in the manual.
  There is also an arithmetic conditional construct (analogous to the
  string-oriented `[[...]]` conditional construct) -- see
  [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)
  and scroll down to `((...))` (there's no direct link).

Comment: okay thanks its working now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, on line 7, you forgot the completing backtick.

Comment: -le or <= which symbol should we use in while ?

Comment: @T.Y.M.SAI Use `-eq -lt -le -gt -ge` for numeric comparisons. Use `= (or ==) =~ < >` for string comparisons.